# Impossible to stop MediaPlayer when push another button

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I dont know how many hours I tried to do this, but its impossible for me fix it using android studio.

When I play a button, and I try to press another, the two overlap and it is really annoying, I need that when pressing one of the two buttons, the audio of one is reproduced and that of the other is canceled, I need not to overlap and not I am able to fix it.

P.S. The audios are longer than 1 minute so SoundPool does not work for me.

```
public void SOUND(View view)
    {
        AZASOUND = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.azaharasound);
        AZASOUND.start();
        if(AZASOUND.isPlaying())
        {
            //AZASOUNDUK.stop();
            //AZASOUNDUK.release();
            //AZASOUNDUK = null;
        }
        super.onPause();
    }

    public void SOUNDUK(View view) {
        AZASOUNDUK = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.azaharausa);
        AZASOUNDUK.start();

        if(AZASOUNDUK.isPlaying())
        {
            AZASOUND.stop();
        }
        else if(AZASOUND.isPlaying()){
            AZASOUNDUK.stop();
        }
        super.onPause();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The sounds overlap because you create a seperate **MediaPlayer** instances in both `SOUND()` and `SOUNDUK` methods. To avoid this, create one global instance of **MediaPlayer** in the class scope, and in each method use this one instance - check if the mediaPlayer is playing - and according to this boolean stop already played sound and play another one.